# Hide a UIBarButtonItem when in edit mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` which has and two `UIBarButtonItem`s:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showSubscribeSheet:)];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
}
```

I want to hide `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` when the `UITableView` is in edit mode. What way can I do this? Thanks.

---

I do not use nibs.

Answer (score 2):

Just set it to nil to hide it

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil ;

Comment: I know but how can I do this whenever the `UITableView` enters or leaves edit mode? This means: when the Edit/Done button is tapped, or when a slide is performed on an editable `UITableViewCell` to delete it, and when that deletion is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

In your selector of the UIBarButtonItem just check the [self.tableView isEditing] where this will indicate that the table view is in the editing mode if it returns true. Else it should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Override the setEditing method:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing...]
    //custom code here
}
```